# Sort an array by time spent, format("86:43")

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array with amount of hours as values. I want to sort this with most time up top and least time at the bottom (descending order). All the examples that I could find were dealing with time, ie ("5:43 pm") instead of a number of hours irrelevant to the time of day. Here is an example array,

```
timeLog = [{client1 : "03:14"},{ client2 : "26:22"},{ client3: "09:56"}];
```

I would want to sort that to be like this,

```
timeLog = [{ client2 : "26:22"},{ client3: "09:56"},{client1 : "03:14"}];
```

Does anyone have an idea here? Being neither date/time nor solely numbers, it is giving me quite a hard time.

Comment: Assuming values are always 5 characters (2 digits, :, 2 digits), wouldn't a normal text sort be sufficient?

Comment: Your data structure is odd. Why do you want to compare three different properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Sthqe/1)

```
timeLog = [{client1 : "03:14"},{ client1 : "26:22"},{ client1: "09:56"}];

timeLog = timeLog.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.client1 > b.client1) return -1;
    if(a.client1 < b.client1) return 1;
    return 0;    
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(timeLog));
```

This works, so long as you don't have a different `key` name in each object, which is totally unnecessary in your example. If each is different, why don't you just make an array:

```
timeLog = ["03:14", "26:22", "09:56"];
```

Or, if they need to be labeled, do this:

```
var timeLog = [
  { name: 'client1', value: "03:14" },
  { name: 'client2', value: "26:22" },
  { name: 'client3', value: "09:56"}
];

timeLog = timeLog.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.value > b.value ) return -1;
    if(a.value < b.value ) return 1;
    return 0;    
})
```

#### UPDATE

I had made a mistake on sorting, I updated my code and fiddle accordingly.

Comment: The compare function must return a number like `1` or `-1` or `0` (if they're equal), not a boolean! That can lead to an invalid sort, depending on the used algorithm

Comment: @Bergi: then replace `return a.value < b.value;` with `if a.value < b.value return -1 else if a.value > b.value return 1 else return 0 ` . Very difficult

Comment: It appears I underestimated javascript's sorting ability.

Comment: Javascript is boss. Use the force, Masters.

Comment: Ah, I figured out why it confused me at first. If i had had values such as {client1 : "15:34"} and {client2: "2:21"} it would have problems because the lexicographical method of sorting would put 15 as a lower value than 2, but since I always have 2 digits, ie 02 instead of 2, the zero makes it sort right.

Comment: P.S. if the hours accumulate to more than 99, it will not sort right unless I add another zero to all the entries, like this. {client1 : "003:23"},{client2 : "110:20"} That way they all have the same number of digits and the lexicographical method of sorting doesn't mess up.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no order for JSON object keys, you will either need to restructure your JSON, or loop through keys and break on the first index.

Working example here (with your current timeLog var):

```
var timeLog = [{client1 : "03:14"},{ client2 : "26:22"},{ client3: "09:56"}];

sorted = timeLog.sort(function(a, b) {
    for (var propa in a) {
        if(a.hasOwnProperty(propa)) {
            for (var propb in b) {
                if(b.hasOwnProperty(propb)) {
                    return a[propa] > b[propb] ? -1 : 1
                }
                break;
            }        
        } 
        break;
    }
});
console.log(sorted)
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NhpR4/1/)

You should try to properly restructure your JSON objects in your application first though.

Comment: This is encouraging bad practice. You shouldn't have to hack like this on an object. Teach the guy proper JSON structure or standards, don't give him a hack.

Comment: I do agree it's not good practice to do this. But it's a good lesson in how JSON objects work and why you want to structure them correctly. I just wanted to give an answer based on what he had to work with. I'll edit the post and explicitly say to avoid this sort of practice if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Okay you handled me :)